# react-native async function failed after reload

Tags: react-native, async-await, es6-promise, reload

I have encounter a really weird issue in react-native on iOS simulation, the following async function run fine after the first build, if I reload then seems like the await function got frozen. If I deleted the app and rebuild again, then it will run fine

```
const processPayment = async (amount: number) => {
    console.log("start fetching")

    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ item: 10 })
      }, 1000)
    })

    console.log(data)
    console.log("end fetching")
  }
```

console log before reload, can run multiple times

```
 LOG  start fetching
 LOG  {"item": 10}
 LOG  end fetching
```

console log after reload

```
 LOG  start fetching
```

Calling function

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {processPayment(100)}}>
 <Text style={styles.keypad}>PAY</Text>
</TouchableOpacity
```

Comment: can you also show the code where you are calling processPayment function

Comment: @adhinarayan I have updated the calling process on the post

Comment: is 'reload' a real reload or a hot reload? In a hot reload a lot of static and async functions get problems. If you re-run the app from Xcode it should be no problem. This is not really an issue for the final app as it will not have hot reload mixing up everything.

Comment: @Christian by reload mean I pressed 'r' on metro window. How would you do a real reload?

Comment: @DanielNguyen then I have no idea

Comment: I have disable the component ToggleStorybook followed suggest from momolafrooo, and the problem seems gone. I should have also mention that I used ignite boilerplate.
https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/discussions/1763#discussioncomment-1650294

Answer (score 1):

I used ignite boilerplate react native and disable storybook component, the problem seems gone.

Comment: Summarize the solution described in the link.  Links may become inaccessible later